# How to run frontend and backend in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor (frontend) and ASP.NET Core (backend) and I can't seem to be run both projects from within Visual Studio at the same time to test the product.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the standard "Blazor Wasm Hosted" template you should only run (start) the Server project. It hosts the Client.

Comment: No offense, but the way to start with a new framework is to work through a video tutorial series.  If you have to ask how to get your project to run, you probably haven't done that.

Comment: This question has been asked before - I can't find it - but here's a gist I wrote as an answer to that question - https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/0ed8d257dff4d8497b97c88e5b2b30d0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Visual to create Blazor, you will see the option `Asp.net core hosted`, if so, your solution will have 3 project in total. Then you **only need to run the server project by default**.

[image]

But if you created a wasm blazor app without `asp.net core hosted` and you manually created another asp.net core project inside the same solution, then you may need to **right click on the solution** and `Set startup projects` and choose all the projects

[image]
[image]